# SDLK Perplexity

Tags: c++, keyboard, sdl

How does SDLK_'anykey' work? In my game, a bullet has to be shot when the Ctrl button is pressed, but through breakpoints and test print statements I have realised that even though I press 'ctrl' once, the function is getting called many times. Why is that? And how do I avoid this?

There's nothing much - this is the switch case in the main loop :

```
            case SDLK_p :
            s.origin(cat);
            break;
```

where s is an object that calls the origin function of the Shoot class, and passes a frame to it. Using a count variable in the origin function, I now know that the function is called for the number of times equal to the seconds I hold down the 'p' key! How to prevent this?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you post some code.

Comment: How does rest of main loop look like?

Comment: Three lines of code you posted aren't enough to figure out the way you handle events.

Comment: Did that..does the SDLK key usually behave like that?

Comment: Code you posted is irrelevant to event handling, just show your main loop please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SDL_PollEvent(&event);
```

You need to check the return value from [SDL_PollEvent](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_PollEvent). If it's 0 there are no pending events and you shouldn't try to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_EnableKeyRepeat), you should add this line to the SDL initialization:

```
SDL_EnableKeyRepeat(0,0);
```